# Magento 2: Multisite not linking correctly

Tags: magento2, multistore

I will have 3 websites (each with their own website/store/store view), but at the moment they are all on one test site example.com. I want a Spanish and French language, I have that working, but instead of going to example.com/es/ I have to go to example.com/es/es/.

I have set `Add Store Code to Urls` to yes because if I don't then the `/es` won't work. The base url of the Spanish site is set to example.com/es/. If I use `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` then it will only link to `example.com/es/` and that won't load the page.

I did create an es folder and symlink `app, bin, dev, lib, pub, setup, update, var, vendor` and copied the .htaccess and index.php file into that folder. The .htaccess is the default Magento 2 one and in the index.php I put in

Here is the index.php file:

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'es';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Eventually the websites will be access via example.com, example.es, and example.fr. For testing purposes I need them to be accessible from example.com, example.com/es/, and example.com/fr/. I am unsure what is the issue with the url.

EDIT:

The following will return `example.com/fr/fr/`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
```

While: 
`{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` will only return `example.com/fr/`.

Why does `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` not return the same url as the php example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` to `{{config path="web/base_url"}}` will return the results that I need. `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` will return `example.com/fr/fr`